# Responsive column number in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've got a bunch of columns arranged like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="col-md-3">
```

These start off as 4 columns in a row and then fold into one column when a certain threshold is met.

Going from 4 columns to 1 is a big change, I would like to have two columns (so 2x2) in between. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below for smaller screens, so that it displays 2X2 on small screens and 1 div in each line on extra small screens.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, had no idea you could string them like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in each column:

```
 class="col-md-6 col-lg-3"
```